# How can I automatically identify multiple lines in an image?

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing

Given a binary image comprising angled lines, how could I automatically identify as much lines as possible? Using the `bwtraceboundary` function in Matlab, I have been able to identify one of them, manually providing the starting coordinates of the identified line.

Could anyone point out a way to loop the matrix of ones and zeros to automatically identify as many as possible?

Here's an example image:

[image]

```
% Read the image
I = imread('./synthetic.jpg');


figure(1)
BW = im2bw(I, 0.7);
imshow(BW2,[]);
c = 255; % X coordinate of a manually identified line
r = 490; % Y coordinate of a manually identified line
contour = bwtraceboundary(BW,[c r],'NE',8, 1000,'clockwise');
imshow(BW,[]);
hold on;
plot(contour(:,2),contour(:,1),'g','LineWidth',2);
```

From the above code we get:

[image]

Comment: Hough Hough Hough*!      (Hough transform for lines)

Comment: Would it be possible to have a minimal reproducible example using the Hough transform in the image I provide? Otherwise, could you please point me towards any useful source of information? thank you

Comment: Hum.... Literally "Hough tranform for lines" gives you an entire tutorial on Google, by Mathworks, that uses the `houghlines` function....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a small example of how to use Hough transform for lines in MATLAB, with some denoising prior for your images.

This code does not detect all lines, and you may need to tune it/change it a bit, and that will need some learning on what is going on, which is out of the scope for StackOverflow. Perhaps someone with more knowledge can find a better method:

```
I=rgb2gray(imread('https://i.stack.imgur.com/fTWHh.jpg'));

I = imgaussfilt(I,1);
I=I([90:370],:);
BW = edge(I,'canny');
[H,T,R] = hough(BW);
P  = houghpeaks(H,5,'threshold',ceil(0.3*max(H(:))));
lines = houghlines(BW,T,R,P,'FillGap',5,'MinLength',3);

figure, imshow(I), hold on
max_len = 0;
for k = 1:length(lines)
   xy = [lines(k).point1; lines(k).point2];
   plot(xy(:,1),xy(:,2),'LineWidth',2,'Color','green');

   % Plot beginnings and ends of lines
   plot(xy(1,1),xy(1,2),'x','LineWidth',2,'Color','yellow');
   plot(xy(2,1),xy(2,2),'x','LineWidth',2,'Color','red');

   % Determine the endpoints of the longest line segment
   len = norm(lines(k).point1 - lines(k).point2);
   if ( len > max_len)
      max_len = len;
      xy_long = xy;
   end
end
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this.  This actually allowed me to complete a Codementor contract :P +1.

Comment: @rayryeng WHERES MY MONYZ :P